# Android Java - How to write class, that may change in the future, to a file

Tags: java, android, class, backup

I am developing an Android App using Java.

I have multiple sets of data stored across various tables. This is managed using classes.

When the user chooses to backup, I am writing an ArrayList of the custom class similar to the following.

```
pfd = cResolver.openFileDescriptor(file_uri, "w");
if (pfd != null) {
    ArrayList<Object> toBackup = dbAdapter.getCustomClassItems();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(toBackup);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
    pfd.close();
}
```

Now, this works, but my concern is that I will need to further extend my class in the future, adding more variables to it, and this might break the older backups.

Is my concern valid, and how would you handle such a scenario?

Comment: I dont know if your concern is valid. You could test that yourself i think. But you could write the data to an xml file as then it does not matter if you later add some extra field tags. So take it in your own hands.

Comment: I strongly recommend using a readable format, such as JSON or XML. Include version information in that format to guide you in how to interpret its contents, so you can load in both older and newer files.

Comment: What CommonsWare said.  Have a version is in your file format, and keep readers in your codebase for the last N versions of the format (N should go back as long as you want to support it).  Each reader should be able to convert it into  the modern format.  Then use a single writer so that the next time you write it out, it writes it in the newest format.  You may be able to write this as a daisy chain, so that the reader for format X+1 uses the output of the reader for format X with whatever changes it needs to make, but that isn't always possible.  When it is it makes things easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually it is sensitive data and I encrypt before writing, which complicates things a bit. Also, the values in the first two index positions are version details. I wasn't sure though, whether the class would be read fine, if the current definition is changed. I guess I can try to convert the class into an array or something.

Comment: Would using serialVersionUID help? https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization

Comment: You could encrypt the xml file.